# failed to open stream: No such file or directory for static-content deploy

Tags: magento2.2, static-content, deploy

I have recently added a new root source css file for magento storefront by putting it in **default_head_blocks.xml** throught below statement.

```
<css src="css/custom.css"/>
```

Now I ran upgrade command

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I am having the same custom.less file at below path of my custom theme.

> `app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/web/css/custom.less`

When I now try to run deploy command Magento is giving me an error

> *pub/static/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/en_US/css/custom.css):   failed to open stream: No such file or directory*

I don't know if this is a version issue or not but I already tried signing off static files from backend by setting

> **`store>configuration>advanced>Developer>Static File Setting>Sign Static Files`** to **No**

as well as trying to run the command again with admin rights.

Still, the error persists.

Comment: did you create custom.css file also at the location of pp/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/web/css ?

Comment: read this block for batter understanding how less css work in M2 https://webkul.com/blog/use-less-magento-2-template-modules/

Comment: Yes, I have created .less file at that location.

Comment: If I create blank .less file, magento is giving an error. Is it normal behavior of static content deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was actually created as custom.less file was blank and therefore magento was not generating custom.css file from it.

I don't know if it is bug or not as blank custom.css file should be generated from respective blank custom.less file.

Adding some css rules to it solves this issue.

Comment: Could you please explain more about this. what kind of css rules are required ?

Comment: Add any css selector with properties in it. In short, file should not be blank.